# Iterate over all columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with 100 columns. I want to perform an operation that compares all of the possible column combinations to each other (col 1 vs col2, col 1 vs. col3, [...] col 99 vs. col 100).

For example:

```
colA   colB   colC   colD
   1      1      2      1
```

so for example a comparison of equal value between two values should yield `yes` for `colA vs. colB` and `no` for colA vs. colC.

Ideally, I would like to only make unique comparisons so `colA vs. colB` is equal to `colB vs. colA` and only one value should be retained.

Is there any efficient way to do it?

Comment: `itertools.combinations(df.columns, 2)`. Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Comment: is col1 vs col2 is identical to col2 vs col1 ?

Comment: @GuyLouzon yes, col1 vs. col2 is identical to col2 vs. col1

Comment: What kind of operation/comparison do you want to perform on the couples of columns? Do you always have only one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import itertools
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
pd.Series(pdist(df.T)==0, index=itertools.combinations(df.columns, 2))
```

output:

```
(colA, colB)     True
(colA, colC)    False
(colA, colD)     True
(colB, colC)    False
(colB, colD)     True
(colC, colD)    False
```

alternative as matrix:

```
import itertools
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(df.T)) == 0, index=df.columns, columns=df.columns)
```

output:

```
       colA   colB   colC   colD
colA   True   True  False   True
colB   True   True  False   True
colC  False  False   True  False
colD   True   True  False   True
```

Answer (score 1):

The 1st thing I would do is set the comparison command
for example

```
(df['col1'] == df['col2']).any()
```

what we need is the combinations of all columns

```
from itertools import combinations
combs = list(combinations(df.columns, 2))
```

now we can loop through them and compare them, using our single row from the top

```
for cmb in combs:
    print((df[cmb[0]] == df[cmb[1]]).any())
```